# Is there a way to update side inputs in Apache Beam?

Tags: apache-beam

I am developing a data transformation pipeline in Apache Beam, where I need some look up table to help with transforming each incoming record.

I can pass in the look up table as a side input, but the caveat is an incoming record could update the lookup table that I am using.

Is there a way to update the lookup table and then broadcast the update to every other worker?

Update: One possibility is to use a data driven trigger to signal an end to the current window when an incoming record updates the side input.  Does side input gets automatically refreshed at the start of the next window?  In my case I am retrieving the side input from an external source.

Answer (score 0):

If the lookup table is related to the key and window you can try using state 
https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html

Otherwise you may need an external data storage. Database or in memory cache. Just be aware of the fact that DoFns are serializable and opening/closing connections need to be done carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but from the article it seems Beam runners can only parallelize over the key.  So two entries with the same key will have to be processed serially, and I would lose too much performance in that case.

Comment: Correct. You can have a shareable state for the elements with same key (customer, product ...). Different keys won't see each other. You don't have a distributed global state with get/put semantics. You can have e.g. Ignite cluster for that and have transactional in memory grid. You can colocate the grid nodes with task managers